# JDBC PreparedStatement parameter literal

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement

Is it possible to instruct PreparedStatement to treat parameter as a literal, i.e. not quote it? In other words, if you have the table

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    field1 varchar NOT NULL,
    field2 varchar NOT NULL
}
```

, can the SQL statement

```
UPDATE test SET field1 = field2;
```

be executed using PreparedStatement so that **field2** is passed through a parameter?

Comment: No, you can't pass identifiers (table, column names) as parameters

Comment: I suspected as much. Too bad, it would be quite useful in some situations.